# Разделить char массив на 2 строки

Tags: c++, строки, char

Имеется char массив с таким содержанием:

```
 char msg1[256]="login password";
```

Как разделить его, а далее записать в две разных переменных типа string  используя в качестве разделителя пробел?

Должно получиться  вот так:

```
string login = "login"
string password =  "password"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методами [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) и [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char msg1[256] = "login password";

    const std::string s = msg1;
    const std::string login = s.substr(0, s.find(' '));
    const std::string password = s.substr(s.find(' ') + 1);

    std::cout << "Login: " << login;
    std::cout << "\nPassword: " << password << '\n';
}
```

Правда не совсем понятно, зачем вам смешивать STL- и C-строки.